# How to use IE Developer toolbar when customizing CRM Forms?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

This is probably one of those questions with an obvious answer, but when I customize a form in CRM it appears in a pop-up without toolbars.

How can I enable the IE toolbar so that it will enable me to easily determine the html elements I need to manipulate in the Javascript?

I'm using IE7 by the way.

Cheers,
Peter.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/226905/does-the-internet-explorer-web-developer-toolbar-work-with-popups

Comment: Spender - Thanks for the referral to the earlier SO question, but upgrading to IE8 is not an option for me at the moment.

Benjynito - I don't understand what you mean by 15 chars??

Comment: sorry, my comment was to try F12 (not sure if it works on the IE7 toolbar).  I had to write 15 characters to leave a note ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Hit F11, copy the full url, open new IE window (with toolbars and such) paste url.
2. Also, make sure that under Settings->Administration->System Settings->Customization "Open Microsoft Dynamics CRM in Application Mode" is unchecked.

Application Mode will always try to hide toolbars and menus.